# Counterexample for a polar decomposition in von Neumann and $C^\ast$ algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

For a von Neumann algebra, we have that partial isometry and positive operator of an operator in its polar decomposition belongs to the algebra, but in a $C^\ast$ algebra this may not be true.

Can anyone help me find a counterexample?

Answer (score 8):

Consider $C^*$-algebra $C([-1,1])$ and its non invertible element $f(x)=x$, then its partial isometry, which is $\mathrm{sign}(x)$, does not belong to $C([-1,1])$.

For a complex counterexample, note that the same example $f(z)=z$ works in $C(\mathbb{D},\mathbb{C})$, where $\mathbb{D}$ is the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{C}$. Indeed, if $f=u|f|$ is a polar decomposition, then 
$$
u(z)=\frac{z}{|z|}\quad\forall z\neq 0
$$
does not have a limit at $0$. So whatever partial isometry $u$ you take, it will never be continuous.

Comment: I was about to post the same example, but in $C(B,\mathbb{C})$ where $B$ is the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{C}$. But since this is so close to your answer, I refrained. Maybe you could add this observation, so that the OP gets a complex counterexample as well, +1.

Comment: @julien You can modify my question. Fell free to edit it.

Comment: Ok, I hope it's ok like that.